# Package cannot find info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to submit my app to the app store.  I have looked at a half a dozen questions similar to this one yet none have helped. 
Here is the error:
[image: Here is the error]

Things I know. The file exist and had the correct path in the Build Settings.

[image: Showing info.plist]

It also exist in Finder.

[image]

Here is what is inside of the info.plist

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I cleaned and build cleaned the project. Even restarted my computer.

### **EDIT**

Here is what the build log looks like when I search for .plist

[image]

The file is found in the project file

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Here is what the build file looks like.

[image]

**EDIT 3**
here is a photo from inside the app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making sure the project has added the info.plist file on the backend? Sometimes, when you create a project, some of the files decide not to be added to the project on their own.

In this image example, I haven't opened by main.storyboard file yet, so it's red (indicating it "doesn't exist"). To fix this, you press the + button and add the file from your project:

This may not show up the info.plist file, however. As you can see in the second picture, it allows me to add in the info.plist file, but my main.storyboard file is currently unavailable.

If this is so, you'll have to select the 'Add Other' button. It'll bring up a finder window and you can select the file *directly*.

If this doesn't work, comment the results, please.

**EDIT: IT WON'T ALLOW ME TO ADD THE IMAGES BECAUSE OF MY LOW REPUTATION ON THIS ACCOUNT**

Comment: I updated my question to show I have the .plist file found in the project file.